# Proof that a particular element of this matrix is always real

Tags: linear-algebra

I have noticed something which seems to be true from numerical experiments, but I can't come up with an actual proof.

Say we take an invertible $n\times n$ Hermitian matrix

$$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\longleftarrow a_1 \longrightarrow \\
\longleftarrow a_2 \longrightarrow \\
\vdots \\
\longleftarrow a_n \longrightarrow \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

so $a_i$ is the $i$th row of $A$, and choose any $r$ such that $1 \leq r \leq n$.

Then define the matrix $n\times n$ matrix $B$ where the first $r-1$ rows of $B$ are the first $r-1$ rows of $A$ and the rest of the rows are the corresponding rows of the identity matrix, so

$$B = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\longleftarrow a_1 \longrightarrow \\
\longleftarrow a_2 \longrightarrow \\
\vdots \\
\longleftarrow a_{r-1} \longrightarrow \\
\longleftarrow\ \ I_{r}\ \ \longrightarrow \\
\vdots \\
\longleftarrow\ \ I_{n}\ \ \longrightarrow \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

To clarify, all the elements of $I_i$ are zero except the $i$th element, which is one.

Now take the matrix $X = AB^{-1}$, and only consider the case where $B$ is non singular.

**My conjecture is that $X_{rr}$ is always real.**

I have found an equivalent statement which is that the dot product of $[a_{r1}\ a_{r2}\ \cdots\ a_{r(r-1)}]$ with the vector of the first $r-1$ cofactors of the $r$th row of $B$ is real, but to be honest I don't think it has helped.

Comment: Note that $B$ will not necessarily be invertible.  For example, we could take $a_i = I_{n+1-i}$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks, I've corrected it now. I'm only concerned with the cases where $B$ is non singular anyway

Comment: It is also notable that 
$$
BA^{-1} = \pmatrix{I_1\\I_2\\ \vdots \\ I_{r-1} \\ (A^{-1})_r \\ \vdots \\ (A^{-1})_n}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let 
$$
A^{-1} = \pmatrix{C&D\\E&F}
$$
where $C$ is $(r-1) \times (r - 1)$. Per my comment above, we have
$$
X^{-1} = BA^{-1} = \pmatrix{I&0\\E&F}
$$
Note that $F$ is invertible whenever $B$ is invertible. Moreover, we may therefore state that $X$ has the form
$$
X = (X^{-1})^{-1} = \pmatrix{I&0\\\star & F^{-1}}
$$
where $\star$ denotes an unimportant $(n +1 - r) \times (r-1)$ matrix.

However, $F$ is a principal submatrix of the Hermitian matrix $A^{-1}$, so it is Hermitian.  It follows that $F^{-1}$ is Hermitian.  It follows that $X_{rr} = (F^{-1})_{11}$ is real, as desired.

Comment: Thanks very much, that's much simpler than I anticipated! However, I'm not sure how to prove that $B$ being invertible implies that $F$ is invertible. Could you expand on that please?

Comment: Note that $BA^{-1}$ is invertible if and only if $B$ is invertible. Then, because $BA^{-1}$ is block lower triangular, it is invertible if and only if its diagonal blocks are invertible.

Comment: Perfect, that makes sense. Thanks!